Why does a magnet fall slowly in a copper tube?
In A level Physics, we learn that when a magnet falls through a copper tube, it slows down because of the induced current around the closed tube.
But as I researched further, I figured out that eddy current is formed in the copper which is what actually slows down the magnet.
Therefore, even if the tube is not closed/connected, the magnet still falls slowly.
In fact, if we unwrap the copper tube completely so that we have a thick copper sheet and drop a magnet next to it, it still falls slowly.
So for a closed tube, is eddy current the only cause of magnet slowing down or is it because of both the induced current around the tube and the eddy current?

Why do you think that "induced current" and "eddy current" are different things?
